# How to inject different environment variable in dev, test, prod in Python

Tags: python, python-unittest

I used to work with Flask which offers an easy way to configure the application running in different modes. (dev, test, prod, ...)

```py
class BaseConfig:
    MY_PATH = "Something"

class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
    MY_PATH = "Something else"

# ...
```

I am trying to build something similar but without using Flask. Here is the structure of the most simple code I could find:

```
-src
  - main.py
  - zip2h5
    - __init__.py
    - foo.py
-test
  - __init__.py
  - test_foo.py
```

The object `Foo.py` has a method `path` which output "path/to/dev" when in dev mode, "path/to/test" when in test mode. Writing `if` statements in the code would be messy and hard to test properly. Using environment variable seems much better. How and where do I set the configurations that Flask does?

```py
# foo.py
class Foo():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def path(self):
        return "path/in/dev"

# test_foo.py
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_path(self):
        boo = Foo("Boo")
        expected = "path/in/test"
        self.assertEquals(boo.path(), expected)
```

Please, do not tell me I can patch the method. As I have said, this is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment for your process is available via the [os module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ).

You can simply inject different environment variables for the path in your dev and test cases. I'm not sure how your running your tests, but usually you can do something like `PATH='path/in/test' tests.sh` to accomplish what you need.

I use the [dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) and keep `.env` files in my project root to manage this. I have a base test class that loads `.env.test` instead of `.env` for testing configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the same was Flask does it.  Have multiple Config classes, then pass env as a parameter e.g

```
class Foo():

    def __init__(self, name, env):
        self.name = name
        self.env = env

    def path(self):
      if self.env == 'TEST':
      #initialize TestConfig class here
         return TestConfigPath
```

## test_foo.py

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_path(self):
        boo = Foo("Boo")
        expected = "path/in/test"
        self.assertEquals(boo.path(), expected)
```

Comment: I have not tested your code but it helps me to solve my real case. I do not see where you set `env` in `test_foo.py`.

Comment: In test_foo.py, you can have boo = Foo("Boo", "TEST").    You should use dotenv for your environment variables.